# Automatic concatenation of rows of different lengths

Tags: matlab

I have a row vector x2, and two other row vectors x9 and x10. I want to extract range of elements from x2 from x10(1) to x9(1) and x10(2) to x9(2). Now the problem is that the length of these ranges isn't the same and hence I am unable to concatenate them.
Here is what I have tried so far:

```
clear
clc
x2=[7901 7905 7908 7912 7916 7920 8041 8044 8048 8052 8057 8088 8269 8273 8277];
x10= [8034,8264];
x9=[8074,8304];

for i=1:2
x4=x2(x2>=x10(i)&x2<=x9(i))
y(i,:)=[x4]
end

% I want to extract elements from x2 within the range x10(1) to x9(1) and then x10(2) to x9(2) so that my result should be: y= [8041 8044 8048 8052 8057 8269 8273 8277]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

```
[ x2(x2>=x10(1)&x2<=x9(1)) x2(x2>=x10(2)&x2<=x9(2)) ]
```

The problem with your code is that you assign each result to a different row, but the results have different lengths, so they can't fit as rows of a matrix. If you want to use your code, change the loop to

```
y = [];
for ii = 1:2
    x4 = x2(x2>=x10(ii)&x2<=x9(ii));
    y = [y x4];
end
```